# How to set a timeout config for lastValueFrom() using RxJS 7 in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular13, rxjs7

[Quote](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#use-one-of-the-two-new-functions) from RxJS dev team:

> To fix all these issues, we decided to deprecate `toPromise()`, and to introduce the two new helper functions for conversion to Promises.
>
> **Use one of the two new functions**
>
> As a replacement to the deprecated
> `toPromise()` method, you should use one of the two built in static
> conversion functions `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom`....

In my case I send a get request to the server to check if the server is available or not. The main function (in this case the `ngOnInit()`) will not go further until an HTTP response or an error comes back.

At [this part of the article](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise#warning), they suggest adding a `timeout` to the `lastValueFrom()` function, which should be added as a config `config?: LastValueFromConfig<D>`.

My code:

```
    let something = lastValueFrom(this.http.get<resultDTO> 
    ('/api/account/test'),).then(
          res => {
            this.note = (res.data);
          }
    );
```

How do I have to set this config and pass it to the function?

Comment: _Should_ it be added as a config? Those docs link to a separate pipeable operator, https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout. As described in [the docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom) and seen in [the types](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/bb3da37fd3f862d09f3c139f647acd694a4c4877/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts#L4-L6), the config is only for a default value.

Answer (score 2):

The [`timeout`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeout) operator must be added to the HTTP request and not the Promise from `lastValueFrom`.

```js
let something = lastValueFrom(
  this.http.get<resultDTO>('/api/account/test').pipe(
    timeout(5000)      // <-- HTTP request will error out if no response for 5 seconds
  )
).then(res => {
  this.note = (res.data);
});
```

---

The [`LastValueFromConfig`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/3a6d1643f6ef9cc28cce0051a805b9ce55ceb7a3/src/internal/lastValueFrom.ts#L4) argument at the moment (RxJS v7) has only one value.

```js
export interface LastValueFromConfig<T> {
  defaultValue: T;
}
```

This has nothing to do with the `timeout` behaviour of the observable.

So in your case you could do

```js
let something = lastValueFrom(
  this.http.get<resultDTO>('/api/account/test').pipe(
    timeout(5000)      // <-- HTTP request will error out if no response for 5 seconds
  ),
  { defaultValue: { data: ''} }  // <-- default value to be used
).then(res => {
  this.note = (res.data);
});
```

---

Being said that, this is one of those cases where I'd say there is no inherent need for converting the Observable to a Promise. You could simply make do only with the observable

```js
this.http.get<resultDTO>('/api/account/test').pipe(
  timeout(5000)      // <-- HTTP request will error out if no response for 5 seconds
).subscribe({
  next: (res: resultDTO) => {
    this.note = res.data;
  },
  error: (error: any) => {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: Then what about this: [LastValueFrom()](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom#lastvaluefrom)      It exactly says: An optional configuration object to define the defaultValue to use if the source completes without emitting a value

Comment: I even see it in my source code in VSCode [https://s21.picofile.com/file/8444203200/2021_11_23_07_40_25_%E2%97%8F_test_component_ts_Doctors_Visual_Studio_Code.png](https://s21.picofile.com/file/8444203200/2021_11_23_07_40_25_%E2%97%8F_test_component_ts_Doctors_Visual_Studio_Code.png)       I just couldn't instantiate a LastValueFromConfig.

Comment: @Matthew: You aren't providing any `LastValueFromConfig` at the moment. See the statement marked as `<-- default value to be used` in the 2nd section of my answer. Also the parameter `config?: LastValueFromConfig<D>` with a question mark `?` means that the `config` is optional and could be ignored if you don't need it.